# c# webbrowser get its url from text box

Tags: c#, forms, visual-c#-express-2010

Ok i am trying to make my webbrowser(webbrowser1) get a url that is read from a textbox (textbox1 ) so the user can pick where the web browser connects from

i have tried:

```
private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {

             webBrowser1.Url = textBox1.Text();
        }
```

And:

```
private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {

             webBrowser1.Url = textBox1.Text;
        }
```

and some outer methods but i can not seem to get it to do it is it possible to do this for  a web browser ?

(i mean a form web browser in the project not Firefox, chrome and so on ... )

Comment: You shouldn't override the DocumentCompleted method.

Answer (score 2):

You're handling the `DocumentCompleted`, which fires when the document has completed loading.

That's probably not what you want; you probably want that code to run when the user wants it.

Comment: could i get a example of how it should look plz

Comment: could i get a example of how it should look plz

Comment: SLaks is correct... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.url.aspx has some simple examples.

Comment: @Gerard2202: You need to learn basic UI programming such as events.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't override DocumentCompleted method. What you want to do is have a button, or in your custom textBox1 override lost focus or one of the action methods. With button override the click.

I guess you could override text changed in textBox1 and detect enter key pressed or some other trigger.

But regardless, you don't want to override DocumentCompleted

```
    webBrowser1.Navigate(new Uri(textBox1.text));
```

would help you navigate to the URL string.

Here are some real simple examples:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.url.aspx